# Запрос к SOAP-сервису на языке Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap

Требуется создать запрос к SOAP-сервису и вернуть ответ в формате `str` с последующим преобразованием в объекты языка Python 3: `list` и `dict`

Answer (score 1):

```
# Документация модуля Zeep
# https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/

from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from zeep import Settings, Client  # pip install zeep
from zeep.transports import Transport


def get_soap():
    """Возвращает данные сервиса"""
    wsdl = 'http://service_url.1cws?wsdl'
    user = "*****"
    password = "*****"

    settings = Settings(
        strict=True  # строгая обработка запроса
        # raw_response=True  # ответ без обработки lxml-модулем
        # force_https=False
        # xml_huge_tree=True  # ограничение глубины xml-дерева
        # forbid_dtd=True
        # forbid_entities=False
        # xsd_ignore_sequence_order=True
    )

    session = Session()
    session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, password)  # Авторизация через HTTP

    client = Client(
        wsdl=wsdl,
        settings=settings,
        transport=Transport(session=session)
    )

    request = client.service.FuncName('param_1', 'param_2', 'param_n')
    result = eval(request)  # Предобразование строки в список словарей

    return result
```

`FuncName` - имя функции SOAP - сервиса,
`param_n` - параметры, передаваемые SOAP-сервису

Comment: `eval(request)` потенциальная дыра в приложении, лучше используйте `ast.literal_eval` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: Перевод документации модуля Zeep https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qkcPhRmZomYRq3Iz5POizOlf_3DlEc89YmyAGShVP1g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Замена `eval(request)` на `ast.literal_eval(request)` (`import ast`) позволит получить тот же результат, но [безопасно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197698/5909792). Т.к. `ast.literal_eval` парсит в структуры питона из строки, а `eval` выполняет код и возвращает результат, и хоть если в него поместить строку с структурой мы получим ее объект, но в той строке может быть и кое-что другое, например: `eval("__import__('os').system('echo %PATH%')")`. Просто, выполнение строки как код, полученной из внешнего сервиса, не безопасно. Даже если сервису доверяем, но останется "человек-по-середине"